# How can I reformat escape characters ready to use as Insert Value for MariaDb?

Tags: powershell, mariadb

I'm using Powershell with ODBC to transfer table data between Sage 50 and MariaDb.

Some data rows in a text column in Sage can contain both single and double quotes that need to be retained when the data is imported into MariaDb.

I'm struggling to get PowerShell to replace for the Values portion of the Insert statement:

I need to replace a single quote  `'` with backslash single quote `\'`, and also a double quote `"` with backslash double quote `\"`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post your code.

Comment: Try the backtick **`** to escape the inner quotes.

Comment: I think the issue I'm seeing is to do with the regex -  though I think I've found an answer at https://vwiki.co.uk/MySQL_and_PowerShell - [regex]::replace($DETAILS, "'", "\'")

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else searching for this the answer is :

```
For single quotes
[regex]::replace($text, "'", "\'")
For double quotes
[regex]::replace($DETAILS, "`"", "\'")
```

I found this URL helpful https://vwiki.co.uk/MySQL_and_PowerShell and as stated you may wish to put this in a function.